# npm debug module: how to display object in fine prints?

Tags: node.js

I'm using this nice node debug module, 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug

All good except debug(req.body)
gives me [object Object]

was hoping to see a beautifully printed json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the npm module you are using is using `console.error` behind the scenes to log the messages.

If you pass an object, it will be stringified (using the [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Description) method). As you can see in the previous link, by default an object is stringified as `[object type]` which in your case results in `[object Object]`.

You can print the whole object by stringifying it. One simple way of doing that is using the [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method:

```
debug(JSON.stringify(req.body))
```

Take into account that this strategy will fail if your JSON object has circular references!